# undefined variable using PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable”  and “Notice: Undefined index”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

I am new to PDO, and i am currently trying to convert all of my `mysql_query`'s to `PDO->` and I keep getting an error of an undefined variable `$db`

here is my code for the Database connection page:

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "XXXX";
global $db;
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname;charset=UTF8", $user, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Edit: my register function that is having problems

```
<?php
###########################
#                         #
# Database Authentication #
#                         #
###########################

require('Database.php');
require('Bcrypt.php');
require('Session.php');

function register($username, $password, $email){
    if($username != null && $email != null && $password != null){
        /*
        $check = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username = '$username' OR Email = '$email'");
        $sql = $check->execute();
        if(count($check) > 0){
            echo "The username or email address you entered is already in use, please try another combination";
        }

                I currently have this commented out to test the INSERT query below
        */
        if(true){
            $salt = create_salt($username);
            $password = hash_pass($password, $salt);
            $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email) VALUES('$username', '$password', '$email')");
            $query->execute();
            return true;
        }
        else{
            echo "Something went wrong with inserting into table";
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Please fill in all of the information in order to register";
        return false;
    }
}
```

When running this i get

> Notice: Undefined variable: db  in ...\Authentication.php on line 33

Comment: Why are you using a prepared statement without preparing the values!?!?!? `$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (Username, Password, Email) VALUES(?, ?, ?)"); $query->execute(array($username, $password, $email));`

Comment: Asking the obvious here, what is line 33 of `Authentication.php`? I assume it's `$query = $db->prepare...` but could be wrong

Comment: yes, sorry for the vaque notice, but line 33 is what you said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `global $db;` statement from where it is into the function scope.

See "Example #1 Using *global*" [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: or you know, not use `global` at all

Comment: At least hes trying to convert his code from `ext/mysql`... use of that extension is the bigger sin if i have to pick one or the other to fix :-)

Comment: Moving it to the function scope worked, but a lot of people are against using global, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: @HurricaneChris Hard to say without seeing the context of your code, but can you pass it as a function argument?

Comment: @Shredder I edited the main question to show full function

Comment: @HurricaneChris can you pass it as a function argument?

Comment: @Shredder any other way to do it besides pass it as an argument? I rather not pass it as an argument because it seems like an incorrect way to do it and anything that required the connection would also have to take in the variable as an argument

Comment: @HurricaneChris That shouldn't matter. You should still be able to pass it as you do other variables.

Comment: @Shredder Would i lose security if i were to do this and have the login page and registration page requiring the Database page? I am extremely focused around security primarily

Comment: @HurricaneChris Why would simply passing `$db` to the function force you to require a Database.php? By the way, if you feel this answered your question, feel free to check 'accepted answer' ;)

Comment: @Shredder because im using it in a different page that displays a register form and calls the register function, and i cannot pass the variable from this page without requiring the Database page

Comment: @HurricaneChris Sorry, not sure if I follow. But no, it won't hinder security.

Comment: @Shredder Last question, should i go with passing it as a variable, or the global keyword way?

Comment: @HurricaneChris pass it as a variable :)

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to pass your `$db` into the `function register` so it will be available inside this functions scope. Make sure you drop the `global` keyword from your `$db` variable first, and you will need to update any other scripts using the `function register()` and pass in the $db variable:

```
function register($username, $password, $email, $db){
//now you will have $db available inside this scope
```

Hope this helps, however as a sidenote this is rather clunky and you should probably focus on setting up your application to use classes instead.

Comment: I have it being required and i still get the same notice / error

Comment: You should get rid of the global keyword, and just make it $db. I didn't know anyone was even still using the global keyword as they are frowned upon.

Comment: Getting rid of the global keyword makes the variable $db undefined in Authentication.php, have any idea how to be able use the variable without using the global keyword?

Comment: Is your Authentication.php a class? If so your going to need to do some changing of your structure.

Comment: Edited the main question

Comment: @HurricaneChris I updated my answer to reflect your edit, give it a try and see how it goes.

Comment: It does work like that, but i rather not do that since i have to require the Database.php page to the page that calls the register() function

Comment: `Best Practices` **VS** `Rather Not` its up to you!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be declaring `$db` as `global` before it has been declared.

Comment: That doesn't seem to cause an error